# What hardware do I need to hang this cabinet on a wall?

Tags: cabinets, hanging

My mother-in-law brought us a very nice cabinet that weighs 30 pounds and is 20"W x 32"H x 4"D. She got it from her parents, and we suspect it was sitting on top of another piece of furniture that we don't have -- there's a "slot" on the bottom of the cabinet that is about 16"x1.5"x1.5" and has four holes on the four sides of the slot that are each about half an inch in diameter and half an inch deep.

I'm picturing that it sat on a credenza that was fitted to this piece, and perhaps it was anchored to the wall at the top through a couple of metal brackets on the top back of the unit that aren't substantial enough to support it at all but are probably enough to keep it near the wall.

Any thoughts on how to hang this on drywall? My idea is a couple of L brackets in studs with a piece of wood attached to the Ls that is fitted to match the bottom and then stained to match the cabinet, although I'm not really sure how to create or acquire that piece of wood.

As recommended by r13, here are some pictures I've added. This would be going onto drywall.
[image: front]
[image: bottom]
[image: back]

Comment: Provide clear photos of the cabinet that show the detail of the slot. Also, indicate what type of wall you plan to hang it on

Comment: Got to have pix.

Comment: Do you plan to put anything inside the cabinet? Any idea of how much weight that might add?

Comment: @HABO, maybe could estimate that we'd be hard pressed to double the weight of the cabinet with the stuff that goes inside?

Comment: Are those metal hanging brackets I see at the top of picture 2 on the back wall of the cabinet? If so, it could be hung like a picture with a wire, if its contents aren't too heavy. The cleat option was my first thought.

Comment: @DAS, yes, they're metal brackets. But I'm not sure how I'd evaluate if they were strong enough to hang from. One of them seems fairly loose, and my completely unprofessional judgment is that I'd feel uncomfortable hanging the unit from them.

Answer (score 3):

Put a "French cleat" on the upper back of it. Mating part on the wall screwed into studs, strip of matching thickness on the back bottom so it does not tilt, hang it.

Alternatively, drill holes in the back of it at stud spacing and screw it into the wall directly.

Comment: That seemed promising but it looks like the edges around the back of the cabinet are only about a quarter of an inch wide, and the main back panel definitely doesn’t seem like enough to be trying to screw into. I think this is probably too narrow to put the cleat on the cabinet?